# Call reference from another solution

Tags: c#

I would like to know how I can call a reference from another solution, below is my explanation:

There are two project solutions in one folder:

- First one has two class files.
- Second one has a console application

Now how can I call the first project's class library from my second project file?

Comment: Refer those class files dll or put this dll file in bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second project, Right click to your `References` from `Solution Explorer`, click `Add Reference` then click `Solution` from the left panel,select your first solution and add it to your `References`.

Comment: Ya I figured it out... Thanks by the way

Comment: @user3338497 if you did, please post your solution. If the solution was the same as +Selman22, please accept the answer.

Comment: @Michel: I did accept the answer. Also solution is given by Selman22 what do u need.